# Need to modify the data type of a view column

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
Alter view [dbo].[M12_qry_DQBase_Figures] 
Alter column [Good_Objects] Integer;

Convert (Integer, [dbo].[M12_qry_DQBase_Figures].[Good_Objects] )
```

**the above two queries are not working to change data type from Varchar to Integer in SQL server** help me if possible

Column details mentioned below

```
Good_Objects: [ARIS_Output].[Number_Objects]-If(IsNull([M11_qry_DQ_Objects_with_errors].[Number_Objects]),0,[M11_qry_DQ_Objects_with_errors].[Number_Objects])
```

Comment: A view is not a table (it's a view, go figure), you need to probably update the base table being queried.

Comment: Learn to ask good questions. Obviously your approach results in some error. Generally speaking, no one should need to guess what your code does. If it generates an error then post the complete error message. And this obviously generates an error. Either alter the query that defines the view or alter the underlying table. Have you tried asking your coworkers for help?

Answer (score 0):

if you need the integer type only in the view you can acess de view script and cast the column from varchar to int, if you need to set and get the value into the DB you must update the view and the table.

note that view works like a "mask" of a select statement or complex procedure/validation.